# WooCommerce Thankyou tracking code installation placement

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tracking, orders

I am new to Wordpress development and am trying to install a traffic junky tracking code on the `thankyou.php` page.

My attempt has failed so far and I think it boils down to not understanding PHP well enough.

The two tracking codes from trafficjunky that were available were HTML or PHP

HTML:

```
<img id="1000143661_tester" src="https://ads.trafficjunky.net/tj_ads_pt?a=1000143661&member_id=1000734841&cb=[RANDOM_NUMBER]&cti=[TRANSACTION_UNIQ_ID]&ctv=[VALUE_OF_THE_TRANSACTION]&ctd=[TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION]" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
    $randomNumber = time() . mt_rand(1000, 9999999);
    $currentPage = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0, 255);
?>
<img id="1000143661_tester" src="https://ads.trafficjunky.net/tj_ads_pt?a=1000143661&member_id=1000734841&cb=<?=$randomNumber ?>&epu=<?=$currentPage ?>&cti=[TRANSACTION_UNIQ_ID]&ctv=[VALUE_OF_THE_TRANSACTION]&ctd=[TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION]" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

I tried to install the HTML version after the order processes under some PHP code on the `thankyou.php` WooCommerce template:

```
**<?php else : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>

            <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                    <?php _e( 'Order number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                    <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && $order->get_user_id() === get_current_user_id() && $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__email email">
                        <?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( $order->get_payment_method_title() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
                        <?php _e( 'Payment method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_payment_method_title() ); ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </ul>
            <img id="1000143661_tester" src="https://ads.trafficjunky.net/tj_ads_pt?a=1000143661&member_id=1000734841&cb=[RANDOM_NUMBER]&cti=[TRANSACTION_UNIQ_ID]&ctv=[VALUE_OF_THE_TRANSACTION]&ctd=[TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION]" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>**
```

This led to order errors so i am trying to figure out how to add the PHP version of the tracking code safely without throwing errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for the replies, I have set up the function in functions.php as instructed but I am still having trouble getting the tracking code to fire. Here is my current code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'tracking_code_thankyou', 10, 1 );

function tracking_code_thankyou($order_id){

$random_number = time() . mt_rand(1000, 9999999);
$current_page = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0, 255);
?>
<em>Your tracking code just below (for testing)</em>
<img id="1000145711_cpa_testing" src="https://ads.trafficjunky.net/tj_ads_pt?a=1000145711&member_id=1000785411&cb=<?=$randomNumber ?>&epu=<?=$currentPage ?>&cti=[TRANSACTION_UNIQ_ID]&ctv=[VALUE_OF_THE_TRANSACTION]&ctd=[TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION]" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
<?php
```

}
}

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42878369/5019802) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42313444/5019802), hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the php tracking code inside the header.php (before the end of the head tag) or footer.php (before the end of the body tag). You need to get the id of the page if you want it to run exclusively on that page only.

Do something like this

```
if(is_page(yourpageidhere)):
//paste the tracking code here
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Instead of overriding the `thankyou.php` template as you can see its source code there is this line:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>
```

Which means that you can use this **`woocommerce_thankyou`** action hook with a custom function, to output anything in this template line. First get the template clean of your code...

Also I have corrected your code in the image link, as it was not correct. You should use the following code in the `function.php` file of your active child theme or active theme:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'tracking_code_thankyou', 10, 1 );
function tracking_code_thankyou( $order_id ) {

    $random_number = time() . mt_rand(1000, 9999999);
    $current_page = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0, 255);
    $url = "https://ads.trafficjunky.net/tj_ads_pt?a=1000145711&member_id=1000785411&cb=$randomNumber&epu=$currentPage&cti=[TRANSACTION_UNIQ_ID]&ctv=[VALUE_OF_THE_TRANSACTION]&ctd=[TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION]";

    echo '<em>Your tracking code just below (for testing)</em>
    <img id="1000143661_tester" src="'.$url.'" width="1" height="1" border="0" />';
}
```

It will output your code just after customers details at the end of the order-received page…

Comment: Sorry was having some issues with formatting there, I put my updated code in the original post. I have tested the function and it is working successfully, but I am having issues getting the Traffic Junky tracking to fire now. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @user2415458 I can't handle the "Traffic Junky tracking to fire now" for you. So as you say "and is working successfully", please you could mark this answer as accepted… Thanks